# Firefox and Chrome update breaks Angular application

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox

We have a problem with a new update in Firefox with our Angular 8 application. We did not change anything in our code but now that the browser has updated when we click on a `RouterLink`, the page does not navigate until another event (any of them) is fired. It looks like we did not click on the link and after another event is pushed, then it navigates to the page clicked before.

Any ideas of what is going on? we have tried everything we could find and nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance!

Module with the RouterModule imported

```
@NgModule({
exports: [
    // ANGULAR
    RouterModule
],

imports: [
    // ANGULAR
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        AppRoutes,
        { 
            onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
            useHash: true
        }
    )
]})export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Component with the links (we don't have the `RouterLink` element because we needed to do some work before navigating)

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" id="menu">

<!--LEAF NODE-->
<mat-tree-node
    matTreeNodeToggle
    *matTreeNodeDef="let node"
    [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': 'calc('+ node.level +' * 10px + 10px)'}"
    [ngClass]="{'menuLevel1': node.level == 0, 'menuLevel2': node.level == 1, 'menuLevel3': node.level == 2, 'menuLevel4': node.level >= 3}"
    (click)="collapse(node)">
    <a class="relative" (click)="clickOnItem()">
        <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <span class="fs-pl-1">{{ node.name }}</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</mat-tree-node>
<!--END OF LEAF NODE-->

<!--INTERNAL NODE-->
<mat-tree-node
    *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild"
    [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': 'calc('+ node.level +' * 10px + 10px)'}"
    [ngClass]="{'menuLevel1': node.level == 0, 'menuLevel2': node.level == 1, 'menuLevel3': node.level == 2, 'menuLevel4': node.level >= 3}"
    (click)="collapse(node)">
    <a class="relative" (click)="clickOnItem()">
        <div fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <span class="fs-pl-1">{{ node.name }}</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="expand-menu-item" fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
        <div class="fs-h-100" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle matSuffix
                    [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="node.expandable" height="24px" width="24px">
                    {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_left'}}
                </mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-tree-node>
<!--END OF INTERNAL NODE-->
```

collapse(node) code

```
this.router.navigate(['main', 'nodes', node.family , node.id]);
    this.treeControl.collapseAll();
    this.treeControl.toggle(node);
    if (node.level > 0) {
        this.expandParent(node);
    }
```

Module declaring the menu component

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [

    // CORE COMPONENTS
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    MainComponent,

    // HELPERS
    PeriodDateFormatPipe,
    SentenceFormatPipe,
    VersionFormatPipe,
    UnitsFormatPipe,
    KeysPipe
],

exports: [
    // ANGULAR
    FlexLayoutModule,

    // HELPERS
    PeriodDateFormatPipe,
    SentenceFormatPipe,
    VersionFormatPipe,
    UnitsFormatPipe,
    KeysPipe,
],

imports: [
    // ANGULAR
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,

    // ANGULAR MATERIAL
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatTreeModule,

    // ROUTES
    MainRoutingModule
],

providers: [
    // SERVICES
    CommunicationService
]})export class MainModule { }
```

Comment: It looks like a common ChangeDetection problem... Are you sure it comes from browsers ? Are you able to run the app with both browser version (where 1 will work and the other not) ? So you have no doubt at all it works for version X, and not for version X+1 ?

Comment: Yes, because half the people in the office had not updated the browser at the time, and it was working. Stopped working after the update. It may be something that was working by chance and when we updated it showed but we cannot find what the problem is. Also, console does not gives any error or warning.

Comment: You may try to add a `(click)=foo()` on each link (making an empty method in the component). It should trigger the change detection and then see if that's the reason. An other clue is how you import the router in the module. Can you add the code of the component containing the links, and the module declaring this component ?

Comment: I edited and added the code.

Comment: Can you show the module declaring your component, and the implementation of the  "clickOnItem()" method ? Is it declared in the AppModule ?

Comment: clickOnItem does not do anything right now @Random

Comment: Where is the code triggering the navigation then ?

Comment: on collapse(node) that is now called navigateTo(node)

Comment: Can you show the module declaring your component ?

Comment: @Random There you go

Comment: Names do not fit. Did you rename `AppRoutingModule` into `MainRoutingModule` ? If not, can you show the code of the `MainRoutingModule` ? My clue is that you used `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` at multiple places...

Comment: Oh... nope sorry. We only used RouterModule.forRoot() once. That can't be it.

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't see anything obvious... would have to debug it live to find it... try to rewrite some stuff from scratch, starting with a simple link that works, and then add all your collapse stuff step by step and see where it starts to break to catch the issue...